# What are the requirements of a protocol factory in python asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I am looking at the example of the [UDP echo server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#udp-echo-server-protocol):

```
import asyncio

class EchoServerProtocol:
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        message = data.decode()
        print('Received %r from %s' % (message, addr))
        print('Send %r to %s' % (message, addr))
        self.transport.sendto(data, addr)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
print("Starting UDP server")
# One protocol instance will be created to serve all client requests
listen = loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
    EchoServerProtocol, local_addr=('127.0.0.1', 9999))
transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(listen)

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

transport.close()
loop.close()
```

It seems that the call...

`loop.create_datagram_endpoint(EchoServerProtocol, local_addr=('127.0.0.1', 9999))`

...is doing all the work here. The [method documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_datagram_endpoint) states the following for the first argument (`protocol_factory`):

> protocol_factory must be a callable returning a protocol instance.

My questions:

- What defines a `protocol instance`?
- Is `returning a protocol instance` a different wording for `initiating a protocol object`?
- How does the `EchoServerProtocol` in the example fulfill this requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What defines a *protocol instance*?

A protocol is a class you define that implements one of the interfaces defined in the [Protocols section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#protocol-classes), i.e. provides implementations for a set of callbacks, e.g. [Connection Callbacks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#connection-callbacks).

So for the UDP echo server example you have posted, the `EchoServerProtocol` user defined class actually defines a protocol by implementing the [`connection_made`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.BaseProtocol.connection_made) and [`datagram_received`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#asyncio.DatagramProtocol.datagram_received).

In summary, if you implement one of those callbacks in a class, you are said to be defining a `Protocol`. So an instance/object of that class would be a **protocol instance**.

---

#### Is *returning a protocol instance* a different wording for *initiating a protocol object*?

Formally *YES*. Before you would return a **protocol instance**, you would have **initialized** it. So basically one is a prerequisite of the other.

---

#### How does the `EchoServerProtocol` in the example fulfill this requirement?

So first of all, as answered the first question, the `EchoServerProtocol` defines a protocol. Thus the next thing is to provide a `protocol_factory`, which is [defined](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.create_datagram_endpoint) as:

> `protocol_factory` must be a callable returning a protocol instance.

So to satisfy this requirement, you could just have this simple method:

```
def my_protocol_factory():
    return EchoServerProtocol()
```

Note, that this factory first initializes the protocol instance and then returns it.

So the thing that might confuse you in the example, is that the class `EchoServerProtocol` itself is passed as the `protocol_factory`, but if you summarize what I've said, you will see that the `EchoServerProtocol` is actually a callable, and when it gets called, i.e. `EchoServerProtocol()` it actually initializes a `EchoServerProtocol` instance, and returns it.

So yep, the example fulfills the requirement.

---

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to do this. But this is a beautiful answer :)
Thank you

Comment: same for me :) glad it helped!!

Comment: also, here is a concise definition from the Data Model section, which defines the classes this way.
**Classes are callable. These objects normally act as factories for new instances of themselves.**